# Swedish letters encoding in different browsers

Tags: jquery, url, unicode, encoding

I have developed a website in which I use jQuery to get a value from a textbox (it is an input tag with attribute: type=text). The reason for this is that I use a the $.get() function and I use the value of the textbox as part of the url, which i use to search a database. This can be a problem if the letters are not in ASCII, so i manually convert the swedish letters 'åäö' to 'char01' etc. to work around it. This is how it looks:

```
        vTxtBox = vTxtBox.replace("%C3%A5","char11");
        vTxtBox = vTxtBox.replace("%C3%A4","char12");
        vTxtBox = vTxtBox.replace("%C3%B6","char13");
```

The problem is that some of my users still experience problems with this so my question is:
Is it possible that some browsers are set to interpret 'åäö' in something else than unicode?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Replacing characters manually like this is not necessary. Use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on every one of your values instead.

See whether that already fixes the problem - if your current page is in UTF-8, things should work. If it doesn't work, come back with more details about the exact problems your users experience.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i don't quite understand the use of  encodeURIComponent(). If I encode the url with encodeURIComponent() I cannot read the parameters on pageload because the url has been encoded. The thing I really wonder is why (or how and when :P) the string i fetch from my textbox gets encoded in javascript without me doing anything?

Comment: of course, stupid of me! Thanks for quick and precise answers!